# home automation with arduino, raspberry using externally powered relay board

Tags: arduino, relay, raspberry-pi

I have a plan to put together small home automation system.

For now I was just playing with smaller parts like single type of sensors at once etc...
I would like to ask for opinion & check of my scheme if basic idea is ok, before I plug everything together.
I saw many variants of externally powered Relay Board, so I am little confused and I am not sure if its ok.

Basic idea is to see data & control everything from website
DHT sensors (read and display data on website graphs)

- only DHT22 nr1 will trigger PC-FANs 1 & 2, when temperature or humidity is too high
- PC-FAN (1 & 2): they run ON all the time (set time from ... to ...)
- LED strip (1 & 2): they run ON all the time (set time from ... to ...)
  (LED strip has to be on separate power line since current A is to high for single relay)
- Soil sensors (1-4) (read and display data on website graphs)
- Water pump (1-4) each separately triggered for period of time when humidity in soil is to low (from Soil sensor 1-4)

Is my plan ok?
Any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

[image: small home automation]

Comment: While your presentation looks great, I think the goal here is to ask a specific question and get concise answers.  Also, there is an Arduino stack exchange.  Regardless, the problem I see is distance limitation...  I'll describe this below in the answer so I can give you a link to the c-bus description.

Answer (score 1):

I see a distance limitation problem.  USB appears to be the link between the controller and peripherals.  That puts about a 5 meter limit on how far away you can place peripherals.  There are workarounds to extend USB (search for "usb extender").  But most use longer distance protocols such as [C-BUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-Bus_%28protocol%29) or [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485).

In [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=65470.0) thread someone posts the link to the [people](http://www.clipsal.com/) who designed and published C-BUS.

In [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=291648.0) thread people are talking about connecting a Raspberry Pi to Arduinos using RS-485 and something called the [Modbus](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ModbusMaster) library.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, so by C-BUS is that mean I2C?

Comment: You're going to wrong way!  I2C, SPI and other similar protocols are meant to be light weight simple ways to communicate between chips on a circuit board.  The are meant to go only inches if that.  I'm having a hard time finding Arduino C-BUS hardware.  So will add links to RS485 to the answer.